# Excel VBA : add calculation to every tables in same sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

this is a update version of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43410090/excel-vba-assign-formula-to-multiples-dynamic-range-table-in-same-sheet).

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ1i5.png)

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkMPb.png)

Thanks @sktneer who helped me out solving the first part of problem, now I want to

1. adjust on the code as I've added a few lines(rows) between table name and
   table, with added columns too
2. add the formula to the right side of the table with table name

I have included some of my assumptions on the code (as comments) from previous answer in "failed attempt" image.
Would you guys please let me know if it's correct?
Because I don't fully understand how did the code works even though I did googled on the statements.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.
The code below will not insert the name of the class while making the Total summary.
But the code will create a summary right to each table as you showed in your desired output, provided there is enough space for summary to the right of each table on the sheet otherwise the code will overwrite any data if found there.

```
Sub InsertSummaryForEachTable()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Integer, c As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws = ActiveSheet

For Each rng In ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 3).Areas
    If rng.Rows.Count > 1 And rng.Columns.Count = 4 Then
        c = rng.Cells(1, rng.Columns.Count).Column + 2
        Cells(rng.Rows(1).Row, c).Value = "Total"
        For i = 2 To rng.Rows.Count
            rng.Rows(i).Cells(1).Select
            Cells(rng.Rows(i).Row, c) = rng.Rows(i).Cells(1)
            Cells(rng.Rows(i).Row, c + 1) = "=SUM(" & rng.Rows(i).Address & ")"
        Next i
    End If
Next rng
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @sktneer, I have tried the above code, its not working (using old table). The sheet remain the same. Also, apologize for not updating the desired output (as I mentioned, I added some columns and rows from previous question, then I tried to change from your code, but fail attempt)

Comment: Insert a blank row and a blank column around each table and the code will work. The code assumes that each table is separated by a blank row and a blank column. If you have some text just above the table, insert a blank row.

Comment: hi @sktneer, I have upload an output of what I have on the sheet now. I get the total for each table but not for the last column (using the previous code provided). And I thought I actually have blank column between column?

Comment: You should be consistent when you show your sample data. Earlier you showed that each table will have four columns name and three subjects. In your new sample there are four columns.

Comment: Hi @sktneer, apologize for not updating my desired output image for this question. The previously posted image is what I tried to get in previous question. But since you suggested me to create a new question, so I created this one without getting the previous desired output. All in all, the reason I created this question, is to improve my fail attempt code (shown in previous question) and to get from table to desired output. Again, I apologize for creating such confusion.

Comment: I am not sure that what are you trying to achieve. Refer to this workbook and see what layout the code will work on. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ozrqj1ca973d4qg/Total%20Summary%20For%20Each%20Data%20Table.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: Download the file from the above link and click the button to run the code. Also make sure that the tables are separated with one blank row and one blank column.

Comment: Okay, thanks @sktneer. I guess the only thing I am trying to achieve now is to get the class name to the summary (right side of table)? Is Offset with xlPart the only way to do it?

Comment: As I told you, that getting Class name is difficult if it's position from the base table is not fixed and in your case the rows in each table are different so the position of the class name from the first row of the table. So I don't think that offset can be used to get the class name.

Comment: If the class name is at the fixed position from the first row of each table like class name exists certain no. of rows above the first row of table, then only it can be fetched in the summary area.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks, i will try to figured that out. But let's say if the case is to pull the data from the column's total (in row), which was generated from vba, should I go for offset or assign them all into variable first?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your question. Please remember if you have an additional question, always open a new question.

Comment: Sure, no new requirement here. May I know what's 3 stands for in (xlCellTypeConstants, 3) ?

Comment: 3 stands for cells with either numbers or text.

Comment: Hi @sktneer, may i know how do this line count total in the row? It is able to add up value in every columns. But I don't get it as there is no mention of column at all ?! 
 Cells(rng.Rows(i).Row, c + 1) = "=SUM(" & rng.Rows(i).Address & ")" .